# Why can't we prove the consistency of ZFC by proving its axioms is satisfiable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, incompleteness

We can prove the consistency of Peano Arithmetics by given a model of natural numbers, within this model, PA's axioms are satisfiable，thus PA is consistent. Why can't we do the same thing to ZFC

Comment: We cannot actually prove that PA is consistent. There are proofs , but either they rely on ZFC which itself cannot prove its own consistency, or on transfinite induction (as in the case of Gentzens proof) which we cannot prove to be consistent either. So, strictly speaking, the situation is not actually better in PA. Gentzen's proof at least avoids the proof in a stronger theory. If we use a stronger theory, we land again in Goedel's second incompleteness-theorem. We can extend ZFC, but the problem does not vanish. So, Gentzen's approach is most promising.

Comment: Well, even describing a model of ZFC - ignoring all proof-theoretic issues, as well as the issue of verifying that a given theory is true in a given structure - is meaningfully harder than for PA: [ZFC has no computable models](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12426/is-there-a-computable-model-of-zfc). This is related to the fact that PA has no computable *nonstandard* models.

Answer (score 3):

I think it may help to think about the Soundness Theorem as saying the following:

> Let $\Sigma$ be a collection of sentences over some language $\mathcal{L}$, and let $\mathsf{S}$ be a collection of axioms of set theory.  Suppose $\mathsf{S}$ proves that there is a model for $\Sigma$.  Then $\mathsf{S}$ proves that $\Sigma$ is consistent.  In particular, if $\mathsf{S}$ itself is consistent then so is $\Sigma$.

So if you prove the "consistency" of $\mathsf{PA}$ by constructing a model for it, using the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then what you have really proved is *relative consistency*: if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent then so is $\mathsf{PA}$.  Of course, you do not actually know whether $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, though it seems very likely.

You can attempt to take $\Sigma = \mathsf{ZFC}$ in the Soundness Theorem, but the question then is what do you take for $\mathsf{S}$?  Gödel's second incompleteness theorem implies that you cannot take $\mathsf{S} = \mathsf{ZFC}$.  Usually to construct a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, your set theory $\mathsf{S}$ is all the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ plus some extra ones, e.g. $\mathsf{I}=$ "there exists an inaccessible cardinal".  But this is not very satisfying as a way to decide whether $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself is consistent, since it's already trivial that $\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{I}) \to \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$.

It is very rare in logic to actually prove that a collection of axioms is consistent; it's usually only possible for very trivial examples.

Comment: Regarding the first point, it’s not super clear how to get from “S proves $\Sigma$ consistent” to “if $S$ is consistent then $\Sigma$ is”. Just cause $S$ is consistent doesn’t make it right about everything. However for effective theories, inconsistency can be proved by a computation so if an effective $\Sigma$ were inconsistent, then $S$ would certainly prove it, provided it can represent recursive functions, which is a very weak requirement. So if $S$ is consistent and proves $\Sigma$ is consistent, it does happen to be right about it.

Comment: (An alternative way to think about it might be “inside a model of $S$ lies a model of $\Sigma$” but that requires similar justification for why $S$ should be right about what a model of $\Sigma$ is. Again we can show it and like the case above, the converse is not true: there can be models of $\Sigma$ inside a model of $S$ that the model of $S$ believes is *not* a model of $\Sigma$. For instance, amusingly, every model of ZFC contains a model of ZFC, regardless if Con(ZFC) holds in the model.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Good point.  To detect inconsistency, $\mathsf{S}$ needs to be able to prove that a set of sentences which purports to be a valid proof from axioms of $\Sigma$, really is one.  The difficulty, I guess, is verifying that "axioms" in that proof really are axioms of $\Sigma$, which could be hard if $\Sigma$ is very complex.